# Having trouble launching Chrome from Selenium on Linux subsystem for Windows

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

This is my first time posting, so I apologize in advance if I'm missing anything glaringly obvious. I'm attempting to launch Chrome via Selenium through python3 on a version of Ubuntu (18.04.3 LTS) on a Linux subsystem for Windows. I have chromedriver installed in `/usr/bin/chromedriver`, and installed the binary through `pip3 install chromedriver-binary`. The commands are:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

When I try to execute the second line, I get the error

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.).
```

I've poked around, and it sounds like I might need to pass in the path to Chrome(), but I'm not even sure if that is the issue or not. I'm definitely about as green as they come, so thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: FYI: You can use the code button (the one with {} on it) or to get nice code block formatting in posts :).  And use backticks for inline code `like this`

Comment: Very cool! Sorry, I posted this in a hurry before I left for work this morning, so thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you haven't started Chrome with a remote debugging port.

Find path to chrome and run with this flag `-remote-debugging-port=9222`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Chrome_Desktop

Comment: I'll have to try that on my machine at home. Reading around though, it sounds like there are issues with getting Chrome to run on WSL, so I might try uninstalling everything and starting from scratch. If I can't get the headless version up and running, I guess I'll just go back to my regular editor.